# Code stops working after executing a file

Tags: python

Hi i tried changing a exe file's name after executing it and did this:

```
import os

outputFile = "C:\\Temp\\Raso\\MyApp.exe"
os.system('cmd /c ' + outputFile)
os.rename(outputFile, "C:\\Temp\\Raso\\0000null0000")
print('Filename changed!')
```

It exe cutes file but it doesn't change "outputFile"'s name. How i can change name of that exe file after executing it?

Comment: Is there an "after"? `os.system` blocks until the process completes, so it's not obvious that `os.rename` has been called yet.

Comment: How i can run both at same time? or changing name of file after execution?

Comment: Look at the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I tried **subprocess.run(outputFile, shell=True)** But still same

Comment: My point is, does the application actually exit? Do you see `Filename changed!` get printed, or is your entire script still waiting for either `os.system` or `os.rename` to return?

Comment: I just need return os.rename and thats enought

Comment: `os.system('cmd /c ' + outputFile)` remove that, and try, that line isn't useful at all